# find the date of last update to sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

i have a database in iphone which is regularly updated.
is there a way to find out the date of last update to the database.
i just need the date and not the data. also don't want to store 
the date of update as a extra column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlite file last modification date should give you that info.

```
NSString *pathLocal;    // Path to your SQlite DB file
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *localAttr = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:pathLocal error:&error];
NSDate *localDate = [localAttr objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
// localDate here has the info you're looking for
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's accessible, but the database files "last modified date" should work.

If the change counter is enough: that's written in the [SQLite database file header](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#database_header) at bytes 24..27.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the data you can insert a new column `which stores the current date` too...

i.e. If your data comes on 25-9-2010 you store the current date in the database and keep on updating it when ever your data updates.. In this way you can get the last update DATE & TIME without much effort.

hAPPY cODING...